# How to install MySQL 5.1 on Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: mysql, installation, mysql-5.1

I researched a lot but could not find any link which gives step by step procedure. Everywhere, there are vague answers. Can someone please give me steps to be followed to install Mysql 5.1 ?

It gives me an error and stop the execution even when i use `-f`.
This is the message from command prompt.

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.1 : Depends: mysql-client-5.1 (>= 5.1.61-0ubuntu0.10.10.1) but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: edited answer - try that

Comment: Same message even after trying `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1 mysql-client-5.1 `

Comment: Are you sure it didn't tell you what the unmet dependencies are?

Comment: it gave me number of unmet dependencies... here they are `Depends: libdbd-mysql-perl` , `Depends: mysql-common`, `Depends: libmysqlclient16` , `Depends: mysql-server-core-5.1`, `PreDepends: mysql-common`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.1 mysql-client-5.1
```

... from the command prompt should just work.

If not, edit your question with the full error messages you are seeing.

Post-installation steps are summarized in [this blog post](http://www.jonathanmoeller.com/screed/?p=2149).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

from the terminal